# go reflect: how to dynamically create a pointer to a pointer to ...?

Tags: go, go-reflect

I would like to create a `reflect.Value` that represents a multiple-level nested pointer to a final value. The nesting level is not known at compile time. How can I create pointers to pointers using `reflect`?

I already stumble at the "unaddressable value" hurdle when trying to create a pointer to a pointer.

```golang
dave := "It's full of stars!"
stargazer := reflect.ValueOf(&dave)
stargazer = stargazer.Addr() // panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value
```

Same for `stargazer.UnsafeAddr()`, etc. While `stargazer.Elem().UnsafeAddr()` etc. works, I can't see how this helps in (recursively) creating a new non-zero pointer to a pointer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code to create a pointer to the value in `stargazer`.

```
p := reflect.New(stargazer.Type())
p.Elem().Set(stargazer)
// p.Interface() is a pointer to the value stargazer.Interface()
```

Example:

```
dave := "It's full of stars!"
stargazer := reflect.ValueOf(dave)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    p := reflect.New(stargazer.Type())
    p.Elem().Set(stargazer)
    stargazer = p
}
fmt.Printf("%T\n", stargazer.Interface()) // prints **********string
```

Comment: I'm amazed at how simple this is, the key is `p.Elem().Set()`! Thank you very much for this super quick solution!